# Spotify Search API, how to set query params to dynamically equal a users input in a search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, parameters, spotify

I'm trying to build a search form that allows a user to search for an artist on Spotify via the Spotify API.  I am able to reach Spotify's data and search for an artist as long as the params[:query] is already defined but obviously I want params[:query] to be defined as whatever search input a user enters..  Very new to Rails, how do I do this?  What I have so far..

Error message I receive when navigating to my artist search page (artists/index.html.erb) while params[:query] is not defined:

```
NoMethodError in ArtistsController#index
undefined method `encoding' for nil:NilClass
```

problem line:

`response = HTTParty.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=#{CGI.escape @query}&type=artist")`

artists_controller.rb:

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    response = HTTParty.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=#{CGI.escape params[:query]}&type=artist")
    @hash_version = JSON.parse(response.body)
  end
end
```

My search form and how I'm searching for artists

artists/index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Artist Search</h1>
<i>(search for artists you would like to follow)</i>
<br>
<br>
<%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag(:query, "Search artist by name:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:query, "", class: 'form-control', autofocus: true, placeholder: "Enter artist name") %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= submit_tag("Search", class: 'btn btn-success') %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% @hash_version["artists"]["items"].each_with_index do |band, index| %>
  <% if index == @hash_version["artists"]["items"].size - 1 %>
    <li class="artist_li">
      <%= image_tag(band["images"].first["url"], class: 'img-responsive artist_img') rescue image_tag("microphone.png", class: 'img-responsive artist_img mic_bg') %>
      <br>
      <h1 class="artist_name"><%= band["name"] %></h1>
      <br>
      <% if band["genres"].empty? %>
        <h5>no genres</h5>
      <% else %>
        <h5><%= band["genres"] %></h5>
      <% end %>
      <br>
      <h5><%= band["followers"]["total"] %> followers</h5>
      <br>
      <h4>(Follow)</h4>
      <!-- no hr with last li -->
    </li>
  <% else %>
    <li class="artist_li">
      <%= image_tag(band["images"].first["url"], class: 'img-responsive artist_img') rescue image_tag("microphone.png", class: 'img-responsive artist_img mic_bg') %>
      <br>
      <h1 class="artist_name"><%= band["name"] %></h1>
      <br>
      <% if band["genres"].empty? %>
        <h5>no genres</h5>
      <% else %>
        <h5><%= band["genres"] %></h5>
      <% end %>
      <br>
      <h5><%= band["followers"]["total"] %> followers</h5>
      <br>
      <h4>(Follow)</h4>
      <hr class="artists_hr">
    </li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```